# Sample image pixel colours

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm currently trying to get a random pixel colour from an image using HTML5 Canvas.

```
var sampleCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    sampleCanvas.width = 50;
    sampleCanvas.height = 50;
    sampleContext = sampleCanvas.getContext('2d');

var sampleImage = new Image();
    sampleImage.onload = function() {
        sampleContext.drawImage(sampleImage, 0, 0);
    }
    sampleImage.src = 'canvas_sample.png';

var calculatedFill = sampleContext.getImageData(Math.random() * sampleCanvas.width, Math.random() * sampleCanvas.height, 1, 1).data;
```

However, calculatedFill is always `[0, 0, 0, 0]`, never anything else (even though there isn't a single black pixel on the image)

Comment: Maybe you have to round your numbers? Isn't `Math.random()` a decimal?

Comment: ^ and `onload` is an asynchronous operation. Make sure you're only grabbing image data *after* the image is loaded and has been drawn.

Comment: Thanks Mike C, that was the issue.